# reset transformation of UIImageView - objc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two imageviews which are transformed like this:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognize
{
    if (tapRecognize == tapRecognizer)
    {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(lineImage.transform, (M_PI /  4));
        [image1 setTransform:transform];
    }
    if (tapRecognize == tapRecognizer2)
    {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(lineImage2.transform, (M_PI / 4));
        [image2 setTransform:transform];
    }
}
```

I also have added the tapRecognizer to the imageviews. My question is how I can like reset the transform, in this case the rotation when a button is pressed. To set it to its original mode. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the transform property to the identity matrix

Answer (score 1):

Set the `transform` to CGAffineTransformIdentity.

Bonus advice: You don't need to compare `tapRecognize` with a gesture recognizer; just look at `tapRecognize.view` to learn what view was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand the answer

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```